# AEM Asset API: Create intermediate directories as required

Tags: java, aem, assets

I'm using AEM 6.3. I'm using the Assets API to upload assets using *curl* commands. This is how I'm doing it:

```
curl -i 'http://localhost:4502/api/assets/newFolder' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"class":"assetFolder","properties":{"title":"New folder"}}' -u admin:admin
```

My use case requieres to create intermediate directories if they don't exist. Something like this:

```
curl -i 'http://localhost:4502/api/assets/intermediate1/intermediate2/newFolder' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"class":"assetFolder","properties":{"title":"New folder"}}' -u admin:admin
```

In the example above, neither intermediate1 nor intermediate2 exist. The curl doesn't work, AEM returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2019 14:13:35 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: cq-authoring-mode=CLASSIC;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 28-Aug-2019 14:13:35 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"class":["core/response"],"properties":{"path":"/api/assets/intermediate1/intermediate2/newFolder","parentLocation":"/api/assets/intermediate1/intermediate2.json","referer":"","changes":[],"location":"/api/assets/intermediate1/intermediate2/newFolder.json","status.code":500}}
```

The 500 error is weird. From logs I can see:

```
21.08.2019 11:13:35.512 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1566396815508] POST /api/assets/intermediate1/intermediate2/newFolder HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.PostRequest Exception during request processing.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetResourceProvider.getDataPropertyKey(AssetResourceProvider.java:412)
```

Maybe the AEM Assets API doesn't support the creation of intermediate folders if they don't exist? And maybe the 500 error is just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options to use the Assets API. you can try any one of the below:

Below examples displays creating 2 new folders in the assets hierarchy.

**Option1**

```
curl -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/api/assets/we-retail/* -F"name=newfolder" -F"title=New Folder"
```

**Result:**

```
{"class":["core/response"],"properties":{"path":"/api/assets/we-retail/*","parentLocation":"/api/assets/we-retail.json","referer":"","isCreate":true,"changes":[{"argument":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder","type":"created"}],"location":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder.json","status.message":"Created","title":"Content created /api/assets/we-retail/*","status.code":201}}
```

**Option 2**

```
curl -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images -H"Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"class":"assetFolder","properties":{"title":"Images"}}"
```

**Result**

```
{"class":["core/response"],"properties":{"path":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images","parentLocation":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder.json","referer":"","isCreate":true,"changes":[{"argument":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images","type":"created"}],"location":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images.json","status.message":"Created","title":"Content created /api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images","status.code":201}}
```

**Single Quotes are not recognized by default in command prompt. Changing it to double quotes should work**

Other way to create the folders forcing primarytype as sling:folder for the entire hierarchy

```
curl -u admin:admin -Fjcr:primaryType=sling:Folder localhost:4502/content/dam/mFolder/aFolder
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solutions didn't work for me. I'm getting the same 409 for the first example, with this error message *{"class":["core/response"],"properties":{"path":"/api/assets/we-retail/*","parentLocation":"/api/assets/we-retail.json","referer":"","changes":[],"location":"/api/assets/we-retail/*.json","status.message":"parent does not exist","status.code":409}}*.

Comment: For the second example, I got a 500 and this message *"{"class":"assetFolder","properties":{"title":"Images"}}"
{"class":["core/response"],"properties":{"path":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images","parentLocation":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder.json","referer":"","changes":[],"location":"/api/assets/we-retail/newfolder/images.json","status.code":500}}*

Comment: It looks like you are not having the we-retail folder in your AEM environment. If you are trying to create the folder at the root level, remove the we-retail in the path and try.

curl -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/api/assets/* -F"name=newfolder" -F"title=New Folder"

Comment: curl -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/api/assets/* -F"name=newfolder" -F"title=New Folder"

curl -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/api/assets/newfolder/images -H"Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"class":"assetFolder","properties":{"title":"Images"}}"

Comment: For some reason "/" is not getting added after the assets, you can refer this screenshot for the exact command. https://www.screencast.com/t/WWd9YpLMmwM

Comment: I see you point. Yes, exactly, I don't have the we-retail folder. That is my point, I want AEM to create any intermediate folder if it doesn't exist. Seems like this is not possible.

Comment: As we are passing particular information (like name and title for the folder), we will not be able to create the parent folders with the same name and title. You can try this if you would like to create the whole hierarchy:
curl -u admin:admin -Fjcr:primaryType=sling:Folder http://localhost:4502/content/dam/mFolder/aFolder

Comment: That really worked. I'm wondering what are the odds of creating it in this way. Because seems like one would be skipping some metadata for each intermediate folder, right?

Comment: Ideally Asset API is looking for specific information on the current folder and does not have any information for the parent folders which is why it is not able to create the parent paths.

But in the last scenario, we are forcing it to create them as sling:Folder, so it is using the same primary type for all the intermediate folders.

Comment: It is me again. I'm kind of newbie with AEM. Is this possible to use *curl -u admin:admin -Fjcr:primaryType=sling:Folder localhost:4502/content/dam/mFolder/aFolder*, but instead of having just the path created, create also an asset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198331/discussion-between-sudheerdvn-and-perimosh).

Comment: What is your actual requirement? There are multiple ways to upload images, either you can write a standalone program to take care of even properties of the folder, you can use the below command for the creating the hierarchy along with the image 
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -F file=@"imageName.jpeg" http://localhost:4502/content/dam/aFolder/bFolder.createasset.html

Comment: I joined the chat